# Splitting Array Into Partitions Whose Individual Sums Cannot Go Above X

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory

The task is to design an algorithm that partitions the numbers (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, .... ,a<sub>n</sub>) **in the same order as they appear in the array** into the following partitions:

**A<sub>1</sub>=** (a<sub>1</sub>, .... , a<sub>j</sub>), **A<sub>2</sub>=** (a<sub>j+1</sub>, .... ,a<sub>k</sub>), **A<sub>3</sub>=** (a<sub>k+1</sub>, .... ,a<sub>c</sub>), ..... , **A<sub>i</sub>=** (a<sub>l+1</sub>, .... ,a<sub>n</sub>)

Where the sum of the numbers in each partition **cannot** go above a certain threshold **X** and the remainders of the subtraction between **X** and the sum of the numbers in each partition are all as close to each other as possible. In other words, the values of (**X** - ∑A<sub>1</sub>), (**X** - ∑A<sub>2</sub>), .... , (**X** - ∑A<sub>i</sub>) are all as close as possible.

**Example:**
Say we have the array **B= [10,4,5,15,6]** and the threshold **X= 21**. This means that the optimal partitions are **[10,4,5]** and **[15,6]** where the sum of the first partition is **19** and the sum of the second partition is **21**. In this example, the difference between 19 (Sum of the first partition) and X=21 is 2, and the difference between 21 (Sum of the second partition) and X=21 is 0. So we have the differences as [2, 0]. And this is as close as you can get to minimizing that difference

**My Question:** How should I approach this? And is there a name for this type of problem that is commonly known among the designing algorithms techniques and problems. I am confident that this problem is solved through dynamic programming with some kind of bottom-up approach. But is there a popular name for this problem that can be looked at as a reference to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant with *"are all as close to each other as possible"*? What exactly is the expression that should be minimised here? For example, if input is `[7, 3, 6, 3, 6]` and `X=10`, then should the answer be `[7, 9, 9]` or `[10, 9, 6]`? And why?

Comment: @trincot, No. In your example, the optimal partition would be **[7,3]** (whose sum is 10), **[6,3]** (whose sum is 9), and **[6]** (whose sum is 6). The difference between the sum of the first partition and  **X=10** is **0** (10 - (7+3)). The difference between the sum of the second partition and  **X=10** is **1** (10 - (6+3)). The difference between the sum of the third partition and  **X=10** is **4** (10 - (6)). So the set of difference between the sums of the partitions and the threshold **X=10** is [0,1,4] and this is as minimal as it can get, it can't get any lower than that

Comment: I don't know how you compare when you say *"it can't get any lower than that"*. The other solution has differences that are [3, 1, 1], which in a way is better, because the first solution has a 4, while this one only has a 3. So what is the **formula** to compare two solutions?

Comment: How many numbers are there typically in B? If there are not too many, it may be feasible to generate all possible partitions and select the best one. The complexity would be O(2^N).

Comment: By as "close to each other as possible," do you mean like [line-breaking](https://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement this algorithm (in Javascript so it can run directly here). I use a for loop with a sum counter to check for each number if we are above X, if yes I created a new list and reset counter.

```js
const example = [10, 4, 5, 15, 6];
const X = 21;
const result = [[]];

let sum = 0;
let listsCounter = 1;
for (const number of example) {
    if (sum + number <= X) {
        result[listsCounter - 1].push(number);
        sum += number;
    } else {
        result.push([number]);
        sum = number;
        listsCounter += 1;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I believe this is more of a greedy algorithm than a dynamic programming. Which does not always work in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for this kind of problem is the branch-and-bound strategy (see Wikipedia). The idea is to generate (often recursively) the tree of all possible solutions using features of the problem, so-called bounds, to prune away dead-end branches.

The problem requires the differences [(X - ∑A1), (X - ∑A2), ...., (X - ∑Ai)] to be "as close as possible." One way to express this is by mimicking the variance function from statistics,

Variance(partitioning) = ((X - ∑A1)^2 + (X - ∑A2)^2 + .... + (X - ∑Ai)^2) / N

Here N is the number of partitions. The partitioning with the lowest variance is the winner.

During the branch-and-bound search, we would build all possible partitionings recursively to find the one with the minimum variance. We could save the complete partitioning with the lowest variance so far. We may use it as a bound, discarding any incomplete partitioning with a higher variance. To make the bound efficient, we would want to find a complete partitioning with the lowest possible variance as soon as possible. That suggests depth-first searching, favoring partitionings with large (equals few) partitions.

---

I have implemented the above suggestion in C++. I show four runs based on the OP's example,

X=21,
B=[10,4,5,15,6],

varying two parameters: to favor small/big partitions with/without bounds.

```
1.
Favor small partitions
Without bounds
*** Partitioning - Variance (Comment) ***
[10][4][5][15][6] - 185.4 (new best)
[10][4][5][15,6] - 166.5 (new best)
[10][4][5,15][6] - 159 (new best)
[10][4,5][15][6] - 131.5 (new best)
[10][4,5][15,6] - 88.3333 (new best)
[10,4][5][15][6] - 141.5
[10,4][5][15,6] - 101.667
[10,4][5,15][6] - 91.6667
[10,4,5][15][6] - 88.3333
[10,4,5][15,6] - 2 (new best)
Total number of partitionings = 10
*** End ***

2.
Favor big partitions
 Without bounds
*** Partitioning - Variance (Comment) ***
[10,4,5][15,6] - 2 (new best)
[10,4,5][15][6] - 88.3333
[10,4][5,15][6] - 91.6667
[10,4][5][15,6] - 101.667
[10,4][5][15][6] - 141.5
[10][4,5][15,6] - 88.3333
[10][4,5][15][6] - 131.5
[10][4][5,15][6] - 159
[10][4][5][15,6] - 166.5
[10][4][5][15][6] - 185.4
Total number of partitionings = 10
*** End ***

3.
Favor small partitions
With bounds
*** Partitioning - Variance (Comment) ***
[10][4][5][15][6] - 185.4 (new best)
[10][4][5][15,6] - 166.5 (new best)
[10][4][5,15][6] - 159 (new best)
[10][4,5][15][6] - 131.5 (new best)
[10][4,5][15,6] - 88.3333 (new best)
[10,4][5] - 152.5 (discarded)
[10,4][5,15][6] - 91.6667
[10,4,5][15][6] - 88.3333
[10,4,5][15,6] - 2 (new best)
Total number of partitionings = 8
*** End ***

4.
Favor big partitions
With bounds
*** Partitioning - Variance (Comment) ***
[10,4,5][15,6] - 2 (new best)
[10,4,5][15] - 20 (discarded)
[10,4] - 49 (discarded)
[10] - 121 (discarded)
Total number of partitionings = 1
*** End ***
```

And the winner is 4, as anticipated. So, even though the branch-and-bound algorithm makes an exhaustive search, effective bounding can make it attractive still.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <limits>

using Seq = std::vector<int>;
using Part = Seq;
Part best_part;
double best_sqr_sum = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

std::string to_string(const Seq& part) { // sequence to string
    std::string s = "[";
    const int L = static_cast<int>(part.size()) - 1;
    for(int i=0; i<=L; ++i) s += std::to_string(part[i]) + ((i<L) ? "," : "");
    return s + "]";
}

std::string to_string(const Seq& seq,const Part& part) { // partitioned sequence to string
    std::string s ={};
    int q = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<part.size(); ++i) {
        Seq sec ={};
        while(q < part[i]) sec.push_back(seq[q++]);
        s += to_string(sec);
    }
    return s;
}

int node(const bool favor_big_part,
            const bool use_bounds,
            const Seq& B,const int X,
            const int level,int seq_pos,
            Part& emerging_part,int sqr_sum) {

    const double MIN_VARIANCE = static_cast<double>(best_sqr_sum)/best_part.size();
    const double THIS_VARIANCE = static_cast<double>(sqr_sum)/emerging_part.size();

    if(seq_pos >= B.size()) { // full partition found
        std::cout << to_string(B,emerging_part) << " - " << THIS_VARIANCE; //sqr_sum;
        if(THIS_VARIANCE < MIN_VARIANCE) {  // check if better than current best
            best_sqr_sum = sqr_sum;
            best_part = emerging_part;
            std::cout << " (new best)";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if(use_bounds) {    // check whether bound apply
        if(THIS_VARIANCE > MIN_VARIANCE) {
            std::cout << to_string(B,emerging_part) << " - " << THIS_VARIANCE; //sqr_sum;
            std::cout << " (discarded)" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // recursion continues

    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(seq_pos+num < B.size() && (sum + B[seq_pos+num]) <= X) {
        sum += B[seq_pos+num];
        ++num;
    }

    int n=0;
    if(favor_big_part) {
        int s = sum;
        for(int j=num-1; j>=0; --j) { // start with largest parition
            const int pos = seq_pos + j;
            emerging_part.push_back(pos+1);
            const int dif = X-s;
            s -= B[pos];
            n += node(favor_big_part,use_bounds,B,X,level+1,pos+1,emerging_part,sqr_sum + dif*dif);
            emerging_part.pop_back();
        }
    } else {
        int s = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) { // start with smallest partition
            const int pos = seq_pos + i;
            emerging_part.push_back(pos+1);
            s += B[pos];
            const int dif = X-s;
            n += node(favor_big_part,use_bounds,B,X,level+1,pos+1,emerging_part,sqr_sum + dif*dif);
            emerging_part.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return n;
}



void main_split() {

    const Seq B ={10,4,5,15,6};
    const int X = 21;
    const bool favor_big_part = true;
    const bool use_bounds = true;

    std::cout << "X=" << std::to_string(X) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B=" << to_string(B) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Favor " << (favor_big_part ? "big" : "small") << " partitions" << std::endl;
    std::cout << (use_bounds ? "With" : "Without") << " bounds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*** Partitioning - Variance (Comment) ***" << std::endl;
    Part emerging_part ={};
    const int n = node(favor_big_part,use_bounds,B,X,0,0,emerging_part,0);
    std::cout << "Total number of partitionings = " << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*** End ***" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I have added code with examples.